# Ubuntu phone as a Web Development Tool

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Ubuntu phone sounds great -- especially the ability to dock it and use it on the desktop.  I'd love to remove one device from my life.  My question is: will I be able to use it as a web development tool?

For example, like most web developers I run test versions of databases (just a few hundred rows) like MySQL, Postgres, and even riak on my laptop. I run servers like Apache too, of course.  And I tweak my hosts and server config files.  I'd need to be able to run my IDE, as well.

Ubuntu desktop does all of the above even on minimal hardware, but what about Ubuntu phone?  Will it be usable for this type of work?

Comment: @DonaldBrown: You should convert that to an answer!  ;-)
(And, unfortunately, it also shows your age!  And Yra's too!!!)  >:)

Comment: @DonaldBrown: yes, you should convert that to an answer =)  As for a screen, I can add an external screen and keyboard.  And yes, this may be a bit impractical (that remains to be seen), but if it works, it's beautiful!

Comment: Converted comment to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it would work in the way you imagine right now.
A lot of talk has been made about all this "conversion" the ubuntu phones are supposed to bring but I have not seen evidence of this working in the current ubuntu-touch builds.

I think you might be referring to the functionality that was showcased with [Ubuntu for android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzc0uMXGFBY) (at minute 2:17) right?
The current builds of ubuntu-touch seem to be very different from this.
Another problem would be the architecture of the phones shipping with ubuntu-touch.
The two phones it will be launched on will have an ARM based processor. So to have any chance of this to work at all you would have to make sure that there are ARM builds available for each of the software products you need to use (every IDE, browser, database server, database manager and so on).

So **no** the upcoming launch of the mobile ubuntu operating system will very likely not fullfil your needs and the use case you have described.

Maybe in 1-2 years... ;)

Comment: Turns out you were right. A couple years later we got Linux on DeX from Samsung. Not precisely what I asked about, but while it lasted, I connected a big screen to my phone and used IntelliJ IDEA (and generally did all my work) right there. It was a beta. I wasn't perfect. But generally it worked really well. Then they killed it :-( I think the problem has more to do with companies wanting to sell as many devices as possible, and less to do with the capabilities of the devices themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real question here is...Do you really want to do all that work on a small phone screen? Theoretically, this will all work as you wish (I used to use Ubuntu on my tablet through a LinuxDeploy install to test a few things). However, it would be more practical to continue using a laptop, no?